# What are the disadvantages of Aspect-Oriented Programming (AOP)?

Tags: aop

What are the possible and critical disadvantages of Aspect-Oriented Programming?

For example: cryptic debugging for newbies (readability impact)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Poor toolchain support - debuggers, profilers etc may not know about the AOP and so may work on code as if all the aspects had been replaced by procedural code
- Code bloat - small source can lead to much larger object code as code is "weaved" throughout the code base

Answer (score 15):

I think the biggest problem is that nobody knows *how to define the semantics of an aspect*, or *how to declare join points non-procedurally*.

If you can't define what an aspect does independently of the context in which it will be embedded, or define the effects that it has in such a way that it doesn't damage the context in which it is embedded, you (and tools) can't reason about what it does reliably. (You'll note the most common example of aspects is "logging", which is defined as "write some stuff to a log stream the application doesn't know anything about", because this is pretty safe).   This violates David Parnas' key notion of [information hiding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding).   One of the worst examples of aspects that I see are ones that insert synchronization primitives into code; this effects the sequence of possible interactions that code can have.  How can you possibly know this is safe (won't deadlock? won't livelock? won't fail to protect? is recoverable in the face of a thrown exception in a synchronization partner?) unless the application only does trivial things already.

Join points are now typically defined by providing some kind of identifier wildcarding (e.g, "put this aspect into any method named "DataBaseAccess*".   For this to work, the folks writing the affected methods have to signal the intention for their code to be aspectized by naming their code in a funny way; that's hardly modular.  Worse, why should the victim of an aspect even have to know that it exists?  And consider what happens if you simply rename some methods; the aspect is no longer injected where it is needed, and your application breaks.  What is needed are join point specifications which are *intentional*; somehow, the aspect has to know where it is needed without the programmers placing a neon sign at each usage point.  (AspectJ has some control-flow related join points which seem a bit better in this regard).

So aspects are kind of interesting idea, but I think they are technologically immature. And that immaturity makes their usage fragile. And that's where the problem lies.
(I'm a big fan of automated software engineering tools [see my bio] just not this way).

Comment: +1, The string matching of method names is an extremely horrible (fragile) way to inject pointcuts.

Answer (score 8):

I think the biggest disadvantage is using AOP well. People use it in places where it doesn't make sense, for example, and will not use it where it does.

For example, a factory pattern is obviously something that AOP can do better, as DI can also do it well, but the observer pattern is simpler when using AOP, as is the strategy pattern.

It will be harder to unit test, esp if you do the weaving at runtime.

If weaving at runtime then you also take a performance hit.

Having a good way to model what is going on when mixing AOP with classes is a problem, as UML I don't think is a good model at that point.

Unless you are using Eclipse then tools do have problems, but, with Eclipse and AJDT AOP is much easier.

We still use junit and nunit for example, and so have to modify our code to allow unit tests to run, when using priviledged mode AOP could do better unit tests by testing private methods also, and we don't have to change our programs just to make them work with unit-testing.  This is another example of not really understanding how AOP can be helpful, we are still chained in many ways to the past with unit-test frameworks and current design pattern implementations and don't see how AOP could help us do better coding.

Comment: Is it really harder to unit test? Shouldn't the unit tests test the aspects and now have nothing to do with depending on how they are woven?

Comment: @Zombies - How do you test the aspects by themselves, since the only way to do that is to include them.  If you weave at runtime then it has to be set up to do the weaving when the test runs.

Comment: Humble question from a newbie: What factory pattern has with cross-cutting concerns? I mean, why AOP do it better?

Comment: AspectJ is useful for more than just cross-cutting concerns. You may find this article to be useful, for example, regarding AspectJ and design patterns: http://homepages.cwi.nl/~storm/teaching/reader/HannemannKiczales02.pdf

Answer (score 7):

Maintenance and Debugging.  With aop, you suddenly have code that is being run at a given point ( method entry, exit, whatever ) but in just looking at the code, you have no clue that it's even getting called, especially if the aop configuration is in another file, like xml config.  If the advice causes some changes, then while debugging an application, things may look strange with no explanation.  This doesn't affect only newbies.

Answer (score 2):

I would not call it a critical disadvantage, but the biggest problem I have seen is one of developer experience and ability to adapt.  Not all developers yet understand the difference between declarative and imperative programming.

We make use of the [policy injection application block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309507.aspx) in EntLib 4.1 pretty extensively as well as [Unity](http://www.codeplex.com/unity) for DI and it's just not something that sinks in quickly for some people.  I find my self explaining over and over again to the same people why the application is not behaving in the way they expect.  It generally starts off them explaining something and me saying "see that declaration above the method." :)  Some people get it right away, love it and become extremely productive -- others struggle.

Learning curve is not unique to AOP, but it seems to have a higher learning curve that other things that your average developer encounters.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the maintenance/debugging argument, aspect-oriented programming tends to go hand-in-hand with all the other aspects of agile software-development practices.

These practices tend to remove debugging from the picture, replacing it with unit testing and test-driven development.

In addition, it may be much easier to maintain a small, clear code footprint with advice than a large, incomprehensible code footprint without advice (the advice being the thing that transforms a large, incomprehensible code footprint into a small, clear code footprint).

Answer (score 0):

Because the power of AOP, if there is a bug your crosscutting, it can cause to widespread problems. On the otherhand, someone might change the join points in a program – e.g., by renaming or moving methods – in ways that the aspect writer did not expect, with unintended consequences. One advantage of modularizing crosscutting concerns is enabling one programmer to affect the entire system easily.