# Spring Roo and aspect-oriented programming

Tags: java, aop, spring-roo

i've been running some experiments of my own with Spring Roo and it seems to be pretty cool, but i noticed that this tool makes heavy use of AOP on the model layer.

I'm thinking about creating a real project using Roo and what i would like to know is:

- Why AOP is everywhere? Is that ok?
- What are advantages and disadvantages of this approach?

I'm quite new to aspect-oriented programming and some guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring Framework has extensive AOP capabilities, and it makes sense to use these in Roo-based applications. AOP allows you to make a nice and clean separation between business logic and system logic. When done properly, you get a more maintainable and understandable codebase.

<strike>The disadvantage is a small performance hit, but not enough of one to make me worry about it.</strike>

To learn more about Spring and AOP, have a look at the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html). Spring uses AOP for things like transaction management and asynchronous operations.

**edit**: As @chedine rightly pointed out, the AOP is compile-time weaved, so the usual AOP performance hit does not apply.

Answer (score 2):

I think, there will not be a performance hit in case of Spring ROO. Since it uses compile time weaving and all aspects are introduced during compile time.

Answer (score 1):

The disadvantages are addressed in this related SO question: [What are the disadvantages of Aspect-Oriented Programming (AOP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875512/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-aspect-oriented-programming-aop)